# How could I revert to latest version of one another branch

Tags: git, github

I have a file which are changed and submit in branch A, but now I don't wanna merge these changes to master and would like to revert this file to the latest codes in master branch, what's the command for it?

Comment: Assuming you want to get the file in Branch A as it was two commits ago, checkout git revert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get the file looking like it does on master *without considering your current history*, would be to get the latest version of the file from master and place it as is on your branch:

```
git checkout A
git checkout master -- file-to-get-from-master
```

(Make sure to use `origin/master` or similar, instead of `master`, if applicable.) At this point that file will appear as a staged change and you can commit it however you'd like.

Once it's committed, if you wish to undo the changes to that file on branch A so that it appears that you never changed it at all, you could use an interactive rebase (git rebase -i) to shuffle your commits around and squash them so that the the changes fall out of your branch.

Note there are other ways to do what you're asking and some of them are simpler than outlined here. But without
knowing what your branch A currently looks like, this approach should work as a catch all.